# Is it part of clean code to include docstrings in Python?

Tags: python, code-cleanup

I am working on a project, and I would like to have my code as clean as I can. I am wondering if including docstrings in a class it is considered as clean code or not. For example, one of my class definitions is as follows:

```
class Hotel:
    """Class to model the rating and rates of a hotel."""

    def __init__(self, rating):
        """
        :type rating: int
        :param rating: hotel rating
        """
        self.rating = rating
```

Is it correct the way I am writing the code, i.e., am I following the clean code standards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean code is partly a matter of opinion. But most of the ones I'm aware of for Python favor including class and method docstrings. For instance, the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) says:

> A function must have a docstring, unless it meets all of the following
>   criteria:
>
> - not externally visible
> - very short
> - obvious
>
> ...

That said, there's more to good docstrings than just having them; a good place to start is by asking yourself, what would I need to use this class (or function) if I had never seen it before?

Comment: thank you for your time. Do you think it is a good idea to define getters and setter within a class or should I follow the Pythonista suggestion which says that they shouldn't be included in the class?

Comment: You're welcome! I don't think anyone can answer that for you, but most of the Python classes I write have no getters and setters, and the rest have only very few.